# TinyMCE tables: how to hide advanced properties?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, rich-text-editor, richtext

I'm using TinyMCE in the current last version (5.0.14) with the table plugin and i'm trying to remove from the menu the more advanced features of the table plugin:

- The table properties
- The table row properties
- The table cell properties

The following properties are documented:

```
table_advtab: false,
table_row_advtab: false,
table_cell_advtab: false
```

although, they have no effect.

Here is a fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/o2e8nhyb/1/ (sorry about not using the SO snippet, something goes wrong with TinyMCE loading additional resources...)

Does anyone have a solution to remove these options from the menu?

Thank you by advance!

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your help, it helped me clarify my understanding of TinyMCE and its options.

So my question is actually: how to get rid of those: 
[image]

I'd like to offer the simplest user experience and these features seem too fine grain for my usecase.

Is there a way to make those disappear? (I also want to get rid of `Row properties`).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you want to remove the setting features of the Table not just the advanced features?

Answer (score 2):

In your JS Fiddle those options are doing exactly what they are intended to do ... they remove an advanced tab of options from the Table, Cell, and Row properties dialogs.  If you comment them out you will notice an Advanced tab appears in each of those dialogs.

For example, here is the Cell Properties dialog with your settings:

[image]

Here is the same dialog with the `table_cell_advtab` option removed:

[image]

**EDIT**:  Based on your comments to my reply let me add some additional details...

If you want to completely remove options from the menubar/menus you have the ability to define exactly what is / is not on the menubar:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menu

Please note that once you decide to do this you have to explicitly state everything you want on the menus.  The documentation page I reference shows the defaults for TinyMCE 5.

In addition, you likely want to look at what you have configured on the toolbar as well to ensure that you don't show anything you don't want on the main toolbar or the floating table toolbar:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/table/#table_toolbar

Comment: :O Ok, I totally misunderstood what these options did... Thank you very much for the answer. So actually, my real question is: I want to prevent the user to access these panels, do you know if there a way to remove the access from the table dropdown menu? I think those options were the way, I didn't find anything else matching :(

Comment: I've edited my question, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've been able to remove some more stuff, but not really the whole thing. I am not using the `menubar`, and `menu` seems to have no effect on the `table` toolbar button's content. I took a quick look at the source code and I found in the plugin's Button.ts file the following in the `table` button's definition:     `fetch: (callback) => callback('inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column')` it seems that `tableprops` is hardcoded and I won't be able to remove it without modifying/extending the plugin! The same must go with cell and row props!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see some of the of the table properties in the Toolbar maybe try this

```
selector:'textarea' ,
                    plugins: 'lists table',
                    menubar: false,
                    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol\n',
                    table_advtab: false,
                    table_row_advtab: false,
                    table_cell_advtab: false
```

If I am understanding your question correctly

Comment: Thanks for your help! To stick with the simplest toolbar possible, I would like to keep the `table` only, and to remove items from the dropdown menu of `table`. I've edited my question. Do you know if there is a way to do so without adding all the items in the toolbar?

Comment: Other option is editing the tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js file removing the properties from there. I have not tested it so i you do keep a backup file handy

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat older thread, but I had the one or the other "problem" My little workaround is to enable the menu bar, change the table menu there and add a new table toolbar

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cf6swa1/

```
  tinymce.init({ 
      selector:'textarea' ,
      plugins: 'lists table',
      menubar: true,
        menu: {
    file: { title: 'File', items: '' },
    edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall | searchreplace' },
    view: { title: 'View', items: ''},
    insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link inserttable charmap ' },
    format: { title: 'Format', items:  ''},
    tools: { title: 'Tools', items:  '' },
    table: { title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable | row column |   deletetable' },
    help: { title: 'Help', items: 'help' }
  },
      toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline | bullist numlist ',
      table_advtab: false,
      table_row_advtab: false,
      table_cell_advtab: false,
      table_toolbar: 'tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol', 

    });
```